# Writing DataFrame column to a file

Tags: python, pandas

Use the dframe from pandas module:

```
df = dframe.resample('t', how = 'sum')
```

And after that I want to write the data in a new file. I use this:

```
with open('dframe.txt', 'w') as fout:
   fout.write(df.price1) #it is the first column
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "does not work" part. We're not mind readers (yet) ;) Try formulating a *question*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`df.price1` returns a `Series`. Luckily `Series` also has a `to_csv` method similar to the `DataFrame's`:

```
Definition: Series.to_csv(self, path, index=True, sep=',', na_rep='',
float_format=None, header=False, index_label=None, mode='w', nanRep=None,
encoding=None)
```

Example usage:

```
df.price1.to_csv('outfile.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
df.to_csv('mydf.txt', sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI there is also:

- DataFrame.to_html()
- DataFrame.to_excel()
- DataFrame.to_latex()
- and many others but not for file serialisation

Only needed to use to_excel: the usage is in the method documentation or on http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `.values`?

```py
with open('dframe.txt', 'w') as fout:
   fout.write(df.price1.values)
```

It returns a list containing all column values.