# How to dynamicaly generate variable names depending on 3 predefined lists (f'{list1}_{list2}_{list3} ') in Python?

Tags: python

I read many questions/answers, but it does not really fit with what I'm looking for...

Here's the "story" : I'm anonymizing 1000 time series and now, I need to analyze how it looks like between real patient time series and the anonymized ones. I have the following parameters to test :

```
list_patient = ['pa', 'pr']   # pa = anonymized patients / pr = real patients
list_param = ['avg', 'std', 'med', 'max', 'min'] # Measures that I want to do 
list_param_physio = ['FC', 'PAS', 'PAM', 'PAD'] # Physiological parameters such as cardiac frequency (FC)
```

And I would definitely prefer to avoid this... : ["3 lessons to make developers cry..." or how looks like a big part of my code without automation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i755v.png).

Just a taste of it :

```
avg_pa_fc, avg_pa_pas, avg_pa_pam, avg_pa_pad, std_pa_fc, std_pa_pas, std_pa_pam, std_pa_pad = ([] for i in range(8))
med_pa_fc, med_pa_pas, med_pa_pam, med_pa_pad = ([] for i in range(4))
min_pa_fc, min_pa_pas, min_pa_pam, min_pa_pad, max_pa_fc, max_pa_pas, max_pa_pam, max_pa_pad = ([] for i in range(8))
...
# Calculte means and stdev for each pa file, add it to a np.array and convert it to a pd.df
avg_pa_fc, std_pa_fc = pd.DataFrame(np.append(avg_pa_fc, (statistics.mean(pa_series_fc)))), pd.DataFrame(np.append(std_pa_fc, (statistics.stdev(pa_series_fc))))  
avg_pa_pas, std_pa_pas = pd.DataFrame(np.append(avg_pa_pas, (statistics.mean(pa_series_pas)))), pd.DataFrame(np.append(std_pa_pas, (statistics.stdev(pa_series_pas))))  
avg_pa_pam, std_pa_pam = pd.DataFrame(np.append(avg_pa_pam, (statistics.mean(pa_series_pam)))), pd.DataFrame(np.append(std_pa_pam, (statistics.stdev(pa_series_pam))))  
avg_pa_pad, std_pa_pad = pd.DataFrame(np.append(avg_pa_pad, (statistics.mean(pa_series_pad)))), pd.DataFrame(np.append(std_pa_pad, (statistics.stdev(pa_series_pad))))
```

So, I would like to create automatically some empty lists with this format : `{list1}_{list2}_{list3} = []` (underscores are between lists as below)

I tried many things, such as :

```
list = []
for i in range(40):
    list.append(f'{list_param}_{list_patient}_{list_param_physio}')
    print(list)
# Output : ["['pa', 'pr']_['avg', 'std', 'med', 'max', 'min']_['FC', 'PAS', 'PAM', 'PAD']", "['pa', 'pr']_....
    
for param, patient, param_phy in enumerate(list_param, list_patient, list_param_physio):
    list.append(f'{param}_{patient}_{param_phy}')
    print(list)
# TypeError: enumerate() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
    
# For anonymized patients : 
for param, param_phy in enumerate(list_param, list_param_physio):
    list.append((f'{param}_pa_{param_phy}').aslist())
    print(list)
# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I also tried to use dictionaries, but with 3 parameters, it begins to be too tricky for me...

If you have any idea, that would be great !

Comment: You're probably looking for `itertools.product()` instead of `enumerate()`? This smells like an [X-Y problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/174780) though. Are you sure you need all those variables? You could get away with having a single dataframe for the statistics of each dataset that you're processing, with the statistics in multiple columns of that df.

Comment: Also note: this might not be the case in your actual code, but you should avoid using builtin python names (such as `list`) as variable names, because now the python class `list` is shadowed by your variable and that could lead to unexpected and hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I have to place all these results in many files and in different folders (as a project in my Master degree, with strict rules). e.g. avg_values_meth1_<param_physio>[_<param>_<value>].csv

Comment: To continue my first comment: `stats_fc = pd.DataFrame(statistics.mean(pa_series_fc), columns=["mean"])`and then `stats_fc["std"] = statistics.stdev(pa_series_fc)` creates a single dataframe for _all_ statistics derived from `pa_series_fc`, and has a column for `mean`, `std`, `min` and `max`

Comment: If you're trying to automatedly define a bunch of named variables in Python, you're usually doing something you really don't want to do.  For example, instead of having multiple variables, you could have a single map, where each key in the map is the "variable name" you want, and each value is the value of that variable.  Setting key/value pairs in a map is easy and "correct" and should give you the same functionality with your code looking just a little different. Creating variables with those same key names is a code smell.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, this sounds great, but would it be easy then to cut it into different dataframes to save them in different files and folders ??

Comment: That's a different problem, and I don't quite understand what you mean.  But using this map idea should get the variable name problem out of the way.  If you mean that you want to select subsets of the single map containing all of the combinations, that could be done in a number of ways.  One way would be to iterate over the list of keys in the map, apply each key against a pattern, and then only collect the key/value pairs that match the patter into a particular dataframe.

Comment: Sure you can save a single column of a dataframe to a file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412181/writing-dataframe-column-to-a-file

Comment: @CryptoFool, I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not really sure to be able to make it properly. I'll try it on tomorrow. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Since you seemed in interested in my idea of using a single map to store all of your patient combinations rather than trying to create a bunch of variable names, here's an example of how to do that.  This initially sets each key(variable) to an empty list, but you can set each one to whatever you want.

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

list_patient = ['pa', 'pr']   # pa = anonymized patients / pr = real patients
list_param = ['avg', 'std', 'med', 'max', 'min'] # Measures that I want to do
list_param_physio = ['FC', 'PAS', 'PAM', 'PAD'] # Physiological parameters such as cardiac frequency (FC)

patients = {}
for patient, param, param_physio in itertools.product(list_patient, list_param, list_param_physio):
    key = f"{patient}_{param}_{param_physio}"
    patients[key] = []
pprint(patients)
```

Result:

```
{'pa_avg_FC': [],
 'pa_avg_PAD': [],
 'pa_avg_PAM': [],
 'pa_avg_PAS': [],
 'pa_max_FC': [],
 'pa_max_PAD': [],
 'pa_max_PAM': [],
 'pa_max_PAS': [],
 'pa_med_FC': [],
 'pa_med_PAD': [],
 'pa_med_PAM': [],
 'pa_med_PAS': [],
 'pa_min_FC': [],
 'pa_min_PAD': [],
 'pa_min_PAM': [],
 'pa_min_PAS': [],
 'pa_std_FC': [],
 'pa_std_PAD': [],
 'pa_std_PAM': [],
 'pa_std_PAS': [],
 'pr_avg_FC': [],
 'pr_avg_PAD': [],
 'pr_avg_PAM': [],
 'pr_avg_PAS': [],
 'pr_max_FC': [],
 'pr_max_PAD': [],
 'pr_max_PAM': [],
 'pr_max_PAS': [],
 'pr_med_FC': [],
 'pr_med_PAD': [],
 'pr_med_PAM': [],
 'pr_med_PAS': [],
 'pr_min_FC': [],
 'pr_min_PAD': [],
 'pr_min_PAM': [],
 'pr_min_PAS': [],
 'pr_std_FC': [],
 'pr_std_PAD': [],
 'pr_std_PAM': [],
 'pr_std_PAS': []}
```

Rather that reduce your data down to a flat list with complex names, you're probably better off preserving the structure.  Here's an example of how to do that.  This creates a single structure where you can access each patient, then each set of physios for that patient, and then each of the stats (avg, std, etc.) for that patient:

```
patients = {}
for patient_name in list_patient:
    patient = {}
    for physio_name in list_param_physio:
        physio = {}
        for param in list_param:
            physio[param] = 0.0
        patient[physio_name] = physio
    patients[patient_name] = patient
pprint(patients)
```

Result:

```
{'pa': {'FC': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAD': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAM': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAS': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0}},
 'pr': {'FC': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAD': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAM': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0},
        'PAS': {'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0}}}
```

Here's a simple example of how to use this structure.  This shows you how to set and reference the 'avg' stat for the 'FC' physio for patient 'pr':

```
patients['pr']['FC']['avg'] = 1234.56
print(patients['pr']['FC']['avg'])
```

Result:

```
1234.56
```

If you want all the stats for the 'PAS' physio for the 'pa' patient, that's:

```
pprint(patients['pa']['PAS'])
```

Result:

```
{'avg': 0.0, 'max': 0.0, 'med': 0.0, 'min': 0.0, 'std': 0.0}
```

This structure will be easy to iterate over to gather or compute values within it without any of your code having any idea how many items there are at each level.

Comment: Wow, that looks exactly like what I wanted, but is it simple then to call it when need ? e.g. avg_pa_fc = pd.DataFrame(np.append(avg_pa_fc, (statistics.mean(pa_series_fc)))) ? How can I "call" the right key ?

Comment: Looking more closely at your sample data, I'm guessing that you want something more structured rather than creating names.  I'll extend my answer to take a guess at what you really want...

Comment: I missed the example code you gave in your comment.  I could take a shot at demonstrating how to call that line of code for each of of the stats for each patient, but I don't understand what `pa_series_fc` is.  If you had a map containing a series for each combination of patients, physios, and stats, where each combination had a key in the map of the form `<patient>_<physio>`, it would be easy to construct that name and then apply it to each physio for each patient in your data structure.  I'd code that up, but I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: I do understand the structure of `patients['pr']['FC']['avg'] = ...` but pa_series is a list of 1000 files for anonymized patients (e.g., path/1_series.csv), each containing 5 columns (Time, FC, PAS, PAM, PAD). For instance, with the structure you proposed, could I do the mean of a single column (and this for each file) ? Then, I need to concatenate both real and anonymized avg values into a single file and to save it as a csv.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with:

```
>>> list_patient = ['pa', 'pr']
>>> list_param = ['avg', 'std', 'med', 'max', 'min'] 
>>> list_param_physio = ['FC', 'PAS', 'PAM', 'PAD']

>>> {f"{x}_{y}_{z}": [] for x in list_patient for y in list_param for z in list_param_physio}
```

This will give you following output:

```
{
    'pa_avg_FC': [],
    'pa_avg_PAS': [],
    'pa_avg_PAM': [],
    'pa_avg_PAD': [],
    'pa_std_FC': [],
    'pa_std_PAS': [],
    'pa_std_PAM': [],
    'pa_std_PAD': [],
    'pa_med_FC': [],
    'pa_med_PAS': [],
    'pa_med_PAM': [],
    'pa_med_PAD': [],
    'pa_max_FC': [],
    'pa_max_PAS': [],
    'pa_max_PAM': [],
    'pa_max_PAD': [],
    'pa_min_FC': [],
    'pa_min_PAS': [],
    'pa_min_PAM': [],
    'pa_min_PAD': [],
    'pr_avg_FC': [],
    'pr_avg_PAS': [],
    'pr_avg_PAM': [],
    'pr_avg_PAD': [],
    'pr_std_FC': [],
    'pr_std_PAS': [],
    'pr_std_PAM': [],
    'pr_std_PAD': [],
    'pr_med_FC': [],
    'pr_med_PAS': [],
    'pr_med_PAM': [],
    'pr_med_PAD': [],
    'pr_max_FC': [],
    'pr_max_PAS': [],
    'pr_max_PAM': [],
    'pr_max_PAD': [],
    'pr_min_FC': [],
    'pr_min_PAS': [],
    'pr_min_PAM': [],
    'pr_min_PAD': []
}
```

You can also use the following code if you want to create the variables without creating a dictionary:

```
for x in list_patient:
    for y in list_param:
        for z in list_param_physio:
            exec(f"{x}_{y}_{z} = list()")
```

However, be careful `exec()` is a dangerous function and should not be used recklessly.

Comment: Nice not needing an external lib to generate names in your first example.  Your `exec` idea is evil though...no reason to go there.  Not only does it have the security problem you mention, but now what do you do with the resulting variables?  Do you run more code via `exec` to iterate over them?  I assume you'd want to at least be building up a `list` in your `exec`, but now you're back to an outer data structure anyway.  Just no reason to demonstrate this anti-pattern IMO.